# How to add a list of keywords to an wit.ai entity?

Tags: wit.ai

I'm new to wit.ai. I'm building a bot that does voice input for an order processing pipeline. In one field i need to input the client location. And this `client_location` entity has a `keyword` search strategy attached to it.

Now i want to add `all cities, towns and villages` to this entity as keywords. Because only one of this will be considered a valid value for `client_location` entity.

But **there are a couple thousands of them,** and adding them by hand, one by one, inside the wit.ai UI, doesn't make much sense.

I want to use a `cli tool` or a `node package` or something - to do it programmatically. 
[image]
How can i do this? And also is ok to have so many keywords for one entity?

Answer (score 0):

For now, the [node.js library](https://github.com/wit-ai/node-wit) can't do training. 
But you can still do it using HTTP REST api, by posting to `/samples` path.

`POST/samples`

The [docs are here](https://wit.ai/docs/http/20170307#post--samples-link).